# Converting a PCB into wires and film resistors

Tags: pcb, resistors, integrated-circuit

I currently have a project in a vehicle in which I want to replicate a small button PCB board with my own buttons using resistance values for the circuit so the car knows which function to activate.

I have copied below the wiring diagram for the PCB board as follows:

[image: PCB wiring diagram]

How would this be implemented with wires and film resistors?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Have you looked up "R2R Ladders" on the web? They may be what your looking for, and simple to make.

Comment: curious. Which product or function uses this method ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would get R1+R2+R3+R4+R5 with no switches pressed, and almost a short with just switch 1 pressed, just R1 with SW2 pressed etc. There is a kind of priority in this arrangement- only the lowest **number** switch can be detected if more than one is pressed.

You can buy resistor values R1..R5 and wire them to switches. You have not provided the values- if they are standard values you can buy those values, if not you might have to make them up with a couple standard values for one resistor.

I can't really help you with 'wiring it up', it's just as the schematic shows. One side of all the switches is connected together and the other sides go to various spots in the series string of resistors.

Answer (score 1):

> With all of the resistors being in a row and the circuit being closed at all times no matter if a button is pressed or not, does that mean the car is likely to be expecting a certain resistance by default (i assume the addition of all resistances?) and then a change in resistance once each button is pressed?

Yes, you correctly assumed how this works.

> If that's the case, how would this be implemented with wires and film resistors?

Exactly as pictured. There is no difference between a trace on a pcband a wire, and there is no difference between a smd resistor and a through hole resistor  (aside from size and thus wattage it can dissipate). Your final product would be an exact copy of the picture.